# A basic sql-query example

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables:

```
NEWS (id, news_content)
NEWS_VOTES (vote, news_id)
```

I should be selecting (*) all values on NEWS, and also count vote on NEWS_VOTES table where news.id and news_votes.new_id are the same.

A little clearer explanation is:

1. I select all values on NEWS table.
2. Depending on "id" value, I also select:

Negative Votes:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM NEWS_VOTES WHERE news_id = (same ID) AND vote = 0
```

Positive Votes:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM NEWS_VOTES WHERE news_id = (same ID) AND vote = 1
```

I need to do this in a single query.

The output on website will be like "This news got 57 positive votes and 67 negative votes."

Thank you.

Ps. I use MYSQL.

Comment: How do you tell negative and positive votes apart? They are using the same query! :-O

Comment: negative and positive votes have the same value for `vote`?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed. Positive votes should be 1 while negatives are 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming positive votes have `vote=1`:

```
select 
  n.id,
  n.news_content,
  (select count(*) from news_votes where news_id=n.id and vote = 1) as positive_votes,
  (select count(*) from news_votes where news_id=n.id and vote = 0) as negative_votes
from news n
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT n.id, n.news_content,
       COUNT(v1.vote) AS negative,
       COUNT(v2.vote) AS positive
FROM news n
LEFT JOIN news_votes v1 ON v1.news_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN news_votes v2 ON v2.news_id = n.id
HAVING v1.vote = 0 AND HAVING v2.vote = 1
GROUP BY v1.news_id, v2.news_id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, news_content, 
    coalesce(v.positive, 0) as positive, 
    coalesce(v.negative, 0) as negative
from news n
left join (
    select news_id, 
        sum(case when vote = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as positive,
        sum(case when vote = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as negative
    from news_votes
    group by news_id
) v on n.id = v.news_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
  n.*,
  COUNT(IF(nv.vote = 1, 1, NULL)) Positive_Votes,
  COUNT(IF(nv.vote = 0, 1, NULL)) Negative_Votes
FROM news n
  LEFT JOIN NEWS_VOTES nv
    ON nv.news_id = n.id
GROUP BY
  n.id
```

Where vote = 1 means positive vote, and vote = 0 means negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

select 
  (SELECT count(*) FROM NEWS_VOTES WHERE news_id = (same ID) AND vote = 0) positive_votes, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM NEWS_VOTES WHERE news_id = (same ID) AND vote = 1) negative_votes
from dual;